# onkeypress not working, please advise

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeypress

The below code seems to be not working in IE. In chrome it only works after the page has been refreshed a few times. Any idea whats wrong? Thanks.

```
SCAN SHIPMENT:
<input type='text' name='scan_shipment' maxlength="30" id='scan_shipment'
maxlength="20" size='30' onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event,this.form)"/></td>



function handleKeyPress(e,form){
     alert("test");   
    var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key==13){

        var age = document.getElementById('scan_shipment').value;

        age = age.substring(1, age.length);
         var appropiateTr = document.getElementById(age);

    if(appropiateTr==null) {
         var $messageDiv = $('#message'); // get the reference of the div
    $messageDiv.show().html('<H1>Barcode not found in this Manifest</H1>');
   // show and set the message
    setTimeout(function(){ $messageDiv.hide().html('');}, 3000); // 3
    seconds later, hide

         var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'error-beep.mp3');
        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        audioElement.play();

    $('#scan_shipment').val("");
        return;
    } 

   ajaxFunction();

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this document: [DEMO1](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) AND [DEMO2](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_keypress)

> You should use event hendler. so you should call a function onkeypress
>   event() hendler.

Comment: I can try using the event handlers but what is wrong in the above way ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `setTimeout(function(){ $messageDiv.hide().html('');}, 3000); // 3
    seconds later, hide` section. What is `3000); // 3 seconds later, hide` should be commented.

Comment: Do you the 3000 should not be there ? The actual code has 3 seconds , later all commented out.